Are software development kits (SDKs) hardware specific or real time operating system specific
I understand that there are different SDKs for developing application for windows, linux and android platform.
I just wanted to know if SDKs used for developing embedded system applications using RTOS can be portable for different microcontrollers (especially with ARM architecture from different vendors) running RTOS for example FREERTOS ?

That’s a pretty broad question. Some SDKs are very specific. Some are cross-platform. But a lot of stuff will nearly necessarily be platform-specific when it comes to IO, sleep modes, etc.

you are asking if unknown software is compatible with unknown hardware

Embedded systems usually mean you want to spend as little as possible on a processor and get as much out of it as you can. That means the most effective SDKs will be targeted for very specific processors. It also means you need a fairly good idea of how the specific hardware works and how hardware works in general. You sound like a software person hoping that you don't need an EE degree to do a good job at embedded programming. Well, if you don't care about the BOM cost you can probably get buy. But if you do ... good luck at creating a cost effective product.
